# Video is not playing on its image placeholder with jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube

I want to play video when click on its placeholder (image). Here is the code.

html

```
 <div class="ytembed">
        <a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27243869?title=1&byline=1&portrait=1">
            <img width="560" height="315" src="http://placehold.it/560x315" alt="Click to play"/>
        </a>
    </div>​
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.ytembed:not(.processed)').addClass('processed').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var width = $(this).find('img').width();
            var height = $(this).find('img').height();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var $iframe = $('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" frameborder="0"/>');
            $(this).parent().html($iframe);
        });
    });
});​
```

Please advise me what to do me. here is the jsfiddle version http://jsfiddle.net/fEzLZ/

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the video to load and then automatically play? Because the video loads fine for me.

Comment: yes its showing but i want to play it as well when click on image thumbnail. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding 'autoplay=1' to the end of your Vimeo url.  The resulting URL should be

```
"http://player.vimeo.com/video/27243869?title=1&byline=1&portrait=1&autoplay=1"
```

Comment: Thanks and i appreciate it. But would it be possible to achieve it from jquery. I mean client may not know about it. So I'm willing to do it with jquery. whether its youtube or vimeo video.

Comment: Hi, the autoplay feature is good for vimeo videos, but youtube videos isn't playing with <code>&autoplay=1</code>. Here is jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/fPDwu/2/

Comment: Your YouTube embed URL was malformed. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hw3W/

Comment: sorry for disturbing again, i just noticed the "http://jsfiddle.net/fPDwu/" is not working ipad, but works well on pc on all browsers. any suggesstion about it?

Comment: Is the video you're embedding permitted to be displayed as HTML5 instead of Flash? My guess is no if it's not working on the iPad, since iPads don't support Flash.

Comment: now its working by adding html attriblue into iframe that is [type="text/html"]